# Python tkinter Entry value addition

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, tkinter-entry

I am making a Python GUI where the user types in int values into an `Entry` widget and then the program adds these values together.

However, for some reason whenever I try to tell the program to add these values it comes up with the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Entry' and 'Entry'"
```

I have looked around but can't find anything on this topic. I have tried declaring the `Entry` widgets as ints and `IntVars` but it hasn't worked so I'm wondering if it is actually possible to add up `Entry` values.

Comment: Learn the basics of Python first, then move on to creating GUIs.

Comment: Short answer: No, not as such. You can access the values _contained_ in the widget object and add them together, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must `get` the string from the `Entry` and then convert it to an integer.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

e1 = Entry(root)
e2 = Entry(root)
l = Label(root)
def callback():
    total = sum(int(e.get()) for e in (e1, e2))
    l.config(text="answer = %s" % total)
b = Button(root, text="add them", command=callback)
for widget in (e1, e2, l, b):
    widget.pack()
b.mainloop()
```